# Why are these aliases failing?

Tags: bash, alias, cygwin

I am attempting to put some alias definitions in `.bashrc`. Like this:

```
#Convienience aliases
alias ll='ls -l'
alias ldir='ls -p | grep "/"'
#Temporary aliases
alias mvFooLog='mv ~/Projects/Foo/Log.txt .'
```

The last alias will work for me, but there seems to be some subtlety which is corrupting the definition of the first two.  When Looking at the output of `alias` in the console, I get something like the following:

```
'lias ldir='ls -p | grep "/"
'lias ll='ls -l
alias mvFooLog='mv ~/projects/foo/log.txt .
```

This is happening in cygwin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first two lines strongly suggest that a carriage return (`\r`) snuck in before the `'`. Try removing it:

```
tr -d '\r' <~/.bashrc >~/tmp
mv ~/tmp ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance,  tr is complaining that ~/.bashrc is an "extra operand"  any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, `tr` doesn't take the input file name, just standard input. I updated to reflect that (just put `<` to redirect), try it now.